# How to pass the results of a function to another function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, ofstream

Im currently making a programming that reads a text file, performs calculations, and then returns the results to a new text file. So far the program return the basic details of the text file, however, Im struggling in parsing the results of two functions that perform calculations, to a writetoFile function(that, as the name sugguests, writes all the output to a new text file).

This is the 2 calcualation fuctions, as well as the writetoFile function

```
//function 1
double robotComplexity(std::vector<std::string>& lines) //takes in the out.txt file
{
    std::string output = lines[0]; //so far only reads the first line of the output file. 
    std::string input = output.substr(18,1);

    double complexity = 20 * atoi(input.c_str());

    if(complexity > 100) {
        complexity = 100;
    }

    cout << "The Robot Complexity is: " << complexity << endl;
    return complexity;
}

//function 2
double robotVariability(std::vector<std::string>& lines)
{
    std::string output = lines[0]; //so far only reads the first line of the output file. 
    std::string input = output.substr(15,2);

    double variability;

    variability = 5 + atoi(input.c_str());

    cout << "The Robot Variability is: " << variability << endl;
    return variability;
}

//function to write to file. 
void writeFile(std::string const& outputFile, std::vector<std::string> const& lines,
               double unitComplexity, double unitVariability)
{
   std::ofstream file(outputFile);
   for(std::string const& line: lines)
   {
      file << line << std::endl;
   }
}
```

I tried using an enchaned for loop of type double but it doesnt accept it, recieving the error, "this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found"

To reiterate, im trying to add the results of robotComplexity function and the robotValdity function to the output file shown in the writefile function. If any further code is required, please feel free to ask. Thankyou.

Edited to include main

```
int main() {

readFile(inputFile1, inputFile2, inputFile3, lines);
robotComplexity(lines);
robotVariability(lines);
writeFile(outputFile, lines, robotComplexity(lines), robotVariability(lines));

getch();
return 0;

}
```

attempted for loop

```
 for(double x: unitComplexity) {
      file << x << std::endl;
   }
```

Comment: Can you please show how you are calling these functions?

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working, as your functions return a single value it's not surprising that you can't use a range based for on them

Comment: When code doesn't work, you should post the code that doesn't work instead of just trying to describe it (which is rarely helpful).

Comment: Seems likely that you are trying to do the impossible, you want to write a range of results to a file, but so far your code only reads the first line, so therefore it doesn't generate a range of results. So really this question is about how do you ramp up the code to read all the input and produce all the output. Is that a fair summary?

Comment: @john the code above is the code that doesnt work. The two functions first shown make calculations based on the first line. I simply wish to parse those values to the function that writes to a file.

Comment: @john  I have added the main file.

Comment: @john is that makes sense to you

Comment: Well, it looks like you are in fact successfully passing the return values of `robotComplexity` and `robotVariability` to `writeFile`. However, `writeFile` doesn't actually use these values in any way. What was it supposed to do with them, and why doesn't it do that?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I wish to add the return values those two functions to the file being written in writeFile

Comment: @IgorTandetnik As said in the question, I attempted to make an enhanced for loop for both functions of type double but recieved the error ""this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik its simply not allowing me to add the result to the list.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik please see my edit, i added the attempt at the bottom.

Comment: What do you need a loop for? You have exactly two `double` values to output.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik a loop to add the results to the list???

Comment: A loop over what? You need a loop when you have many of something. Here, you have exactly two values. Just output one, then output the other.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i dont wish to output, i want to add them to the file.

Comment: Add one to the file, then add the other.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik how to do this? im not sure. Does each function need to have their own list? then add that list to the file?

Comment: `file << unitComplexity << std::endl << unitVariability << std::endl;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thankyou it works! Another side question, in my main i declare robotComplexity and robotVariability twice, once on their own and then again as paramaters for the writeFile function, thus it prints twice. Should i simply remove the first time i call them?

Comment: Yes you likely should.